# Rails: Routing in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-routing

I'm creating a rails app in this app I have Companies and each company has many jobs I’m wondering how can I route for all jobs of a company X so I will have a URL like this `http://localhost:3000/companies/google/jobs`

Answer (score 1):

Ok i find the answer this is can be done by using member

```
  resources :companies do
    member do
      get 'jobs'
    end
  end
```

this will give the following url

```
/companies/company_id/jobs
```